# open graph tags not working, at the same time google+ working fine

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

http://www.malayalam-dictionary.com/ has been developed Facebook open graph tag with the instruction of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

when share link through facebook, it doesn't working
[image]

At the same time google+ shows exactly how expected :) 
[image]

Here is code

```
<meta property="og:title" content="A complete Malayalam English Dictionary" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.malayalam-dictionary.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.malayalam-dictionary.com/images/logo.jpeg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="malayalam-dictionary.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A complete Malayalam dictionary." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001641332681" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.malayalam-dictionary.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook share url thumbnail problem](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4967979/facebook-share-url-thumbnail-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows up perfectly fine when i put it in facebook.

If the OG Tags don´t work, always check the link in the debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.malayalam-dictionary.com%2F

It also refreshes the OG data.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, let me double check everything

DO you think something wrong somewhere from beginning of the code `<!DOCTYPE> ` ?

Comment: nope, as far as i can see the code looks perfectly fine. it also works in the debugger, the only warning is that the image should be at least 200x200 pixels, but it´s no big deal and it works like this.